# How to insert a dynamic form as an activity or resource in between the sections on the moodle course?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

We have tried to insert form elements via quiz actvity in moodle but when it is much complicated to handle when we display on the front end.

Please refer the screenshot below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b1TI.png

Kindly give some input about how to insert a dynamic form as an activity or resource in between the sections?

Here is actual flow we wanted to implement (like wordpress):

1. Create a form as we want.
2. Like to insert the form id [in the form of shortcode or similar way] in the activity of the section.

Is there any possibility to implement like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the collapsed topics format, since you referred to sections.

I tried formatting a course as collapsed topics and then dragging a form to in between the topics whilst in edit mode, but that is not possible.

If you switch to Onetopic format (which gives you a tab for each week or section of the course), you could put the choice form at the bottom of each tab.